# Parse IP address from ARP command BATCH

Tags: batch-file, ip-address, mac-address, arp

OK, I need to set the IP address of a mac address from the ARP -A command into a variable.

Here's what I get from the arp -a command:

C:>arp -a

```
Interface: 192.168.1.17 --- 0xb
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           74-41-01-42-aa-df     dynamic
  192.168.1.5           d8-d8-cb-23-28-ab     dynamic
  192.168.1.13          18-e6-f4-86-75-9e     dynamic
  192.168.1.14          20-9c-8f-3f-03-9b     dynamic
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            06-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.252           01-05-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-4e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

I need a batch file to find the line with the mac address of 18-e6-f4-86-75-9e, and then take the IP address listed to the left and set it as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find` command to isolate the line with the MAC address you want, then use the `for` command extract the IP address:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in ('arp -a ^| find /i "18-e6-f4-86-75-9e"') do set ip=%%i
echo %ip%
```