# How to save all ip addresses connected to the network in a text file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, ip

I would like to create an alert software for employees without outsourcing for security reasons. I found a way to send alerts from cmd with msg command, I didn't test this code but I generated it from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg) site, if there is any error please let me know

```
msg @allip.txt "test"
```

For IP list, I found a solution using `arp -a` using cmd but I have to clear the extra info in the file like this, the problem is that if I leave the extra info in the text the code doesn't work

```
Interface: 192.168.1.140 --- 0x3
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           00-00-00-00-00-00     dynamic   
  192.168.1.61          00-00-00-00-00-00     dynamic   
  192.168.1.255         00-00-00-00-00-00     static    
  ...
```

Is there a way to save only the **internet address** table

Comment: There is a reason that your first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530068/i-want-to-save-all-ip-addresses-connected-to-the-network-using-cmd) was closed. Please take the [tour]. Please read [ask] a good question. Then please [edit] your question with a [mcve] of the code you are trying to use.

Comment: Regardless of that the `arp` command will not give you a list of all computers on your network.

Comment: I don't want this to be done by the device name because the employees are able to change it, I want it to be done by the ip because the devices are wired

Comment: I have no idea why you are mentioning device name.  I did not say anything about it in my comments.  Regardless, you talk about **SECURITY** in your original question but then mention in a comment that employees are allowed to change their device names. This makes me wonder what other things your employees are allowed to do. You have a gaping security hole without having to outsource this code.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you could not find an existing answer just by searching the site.  I searched for **[batch-file] arp** and this was the first link it found. [Parse IP address from ARP command BATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432369/parse-ip-address-from-arp-command-batch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all the *cached* IP addresses - which is what [`arp.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/arp) `/a` reports - use the following:

- Note: Judging by the linked docs, these **cached addresses**, stored along with their "their resolved Ethernet or Token Ring physical addresses", with a separate table maintained for each network adapter, are the IP addresses the computer at hand *has actively talked to* in the current OS session, which is ***not* the same as the complete set of computers connected to the network**.
  To **scan an entire subnet for *reachable* IP addresses**, consider a third-party function such as [`Ping-Subnet`](https://github.com/proxb/AsyncFunctions/blob/master/Test-ConnectionAsync.ps1).

```
((arp /a) -match '^\s+\d').ForEach({ (-split $_)[0] })
```

To save to a file, say `ips.txt`, append `> ips.txt` or `| Set-Content ips.txt`.

Note:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, you'll get different character encodings by these file-saving methods (UTF-16 LE ("Unicode") for `>` / ANSI for `Set-Content`)
- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you'll get BOM-less UTF-8 files by (consistent) default.

Use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s `-Encoding` parameter to control the encoding explicitly.

**Explanation**:

- [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch)  `'^\s+\d'` filters the array of lines output by `arp /a` to include only those starting with (`^`) at least one (`+`) whitespace char. (`\`), followed by a decimal digit (`\d`) - this limits the output lines to the lines showing cache-table entries.
- [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) executes a script block (`{ ... }`) for each matching line.
- The unary form of `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), splits each matching line into an array of fields by whitespace, and index `[0]` returns the first such field.